# Passing multiple URL parameters to Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

**Edit: Turns out my JavaScript function is not working as I thought, but please help with the ASP issue whilst I fix the JavaScript.**

**Edit 2:**
Using alert(JSON.stringify(sales)) to see the object I get this:

```
{"712":{"KR":1,"LR":0},"713":{"KR":1,"LR":0}}
```

**Edit 3:**

Need to re-write my sales script, i'm trying to use objects but it doesn't seem to be working as I don't have much experience with this part of JS.

```
var products = { 
    "KR" : 4,
    "LR" : 6 
};
var sale = [ ];

function sale(id,product,value) 
{
    this.id = function prod(product,value) 
    {
        this.product = product;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

sale("N51","KR",0);
```

Hopefully you can see what i'm trying to do, but it is probably very wrong.

And thanks for that long post, it is very helpful, I will work on all of that as soon as the above code works

---

Okay, I have this JavaScript script that will sort out the sales for individual images.

712 and 713 is the image ID. Then KR and LR are the products, it only adds them to the URL variable if there is actually a sale for them.

```
function submitSales() 
{
    //URL Variable
    var urlVariable = "?sales=";

    for (x in sales)
    {
        urlVariable = urlVariable + x + "-";
        for (s in sales[x])
        {
            if (sales[x][s] > 0)
            {
                urlVariable = urlVariable + s + ":" + sales[x][s] + ",";
            }
        }
    }
    urlVariable = urlVariable.substring(0, urlVariable.length - 1);
}
```

If I add sales for 3 products I get left with the following string:
?sales=712-KR:1,LR:1,713-KR:1

Now what would the best way of first of all separating the two images sales, so I will be left with:

712-KR:1,LR:1
713-KR:1

Then really I need to have them in a array that would look something like:

```
image(0) = 712 = product(0) = KR = 1
                 product(1) = LR = 1
image(1) = 713 = product(0) = KR = 1
```

I don't really know how ASP array's work that well, from what I read they actually suck.

Comment: Please post the structure of your `sales` object in JS.

Comment: The ASP won't get that structure though, it will get what ever is passed through the url variable.

Comment: BTW, of course you could use JScript instead of VBScript on the ASP side. In this case you could simply pass the entire JS object as a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't really know how ASP array's work that well, from what I read they actually suck.

They do, but in this case it does not matter.

### General Stuff

First off, your JavaScript is wrong.

- `x` and `s` are never declared, thus they are global. Don't do this, always declare all variables with `var`.
- You are not properly encoding your URL parameters. This is bound to blow up, always use proper encoding (`encodeURIComponent()` in this case).
- Avoid relying on global variables. Pass in the `sales` variable as an argument.
- Avoid a naked `for .. in` to iterate an object. Use `hasOwnProperty()` as a security precaution. This is good practice to defend against the case where the Object prototype has been extended. Alternatively, use one of the many JS librarys that give you a universal `each()` function. Underscore.js, Sugar.js, jQuery, all provide such a function. Or write one yourself, like I did below.

Secondly, ASP already solves this problem very nicely.

If you pass multiple parameters with the same name in your query string, the server puts them in a collection for you. (In fact, the `Request` object *always* contains collections, even if you pass in an URL-parameter only once.)

So when you query

```
http://foo/bar?sale=712-KR%3A1&sale=712-LR%3A1&sale=713-KR%3A1
```

<sup>*Note the encoded `:`*</sup>

then the ASP engine will deliver three distinct values, in one collection, like this:

```
"712-KR:1", "712-LR:1", "713-KR:1"
```

- This collection is 1-based, so that `Request("sale")(1)` will be `"712-KR:1"` and so on.
- You can use `Request("sale").Count` to find out how many parameters with any given name there are.

At this point I suggest two things.

- Rewrite your client code so that it sends multiple parameters with the same name.
- Switch to [dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) on the ASP side instead of trying to use arrays.

### Client

js Helper (this might actually be unnecessary if you are using a library already)

```
function each(obj, callback) {
    var key;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            callback(key, obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

js

```
function submitSales(sales) {
    var urlVariable, params = [];

    each(sales, function (saleId, sale) {
       each(sale, function (itemId, val) {
           var param = saleId + "-" + itemId + ":" + val;

           if (val > 0) {
               params.push( encodeURIComponent(param) );
           }
       });
    });

    urlVariable = "?sale=" + params.join("&sale=");

    // ...
}
```

### Server

ASP helpers

```vb
Function NewDict() 
    Set NewDict = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Function

Function Count(ary)
    If IsArray(ary) Then
        Count = UBound(ary) - LBound(ary) + 1
    Else
        Count = vbEmpty
    End If
End Function
```

ASP

```vb
Function ParseSales(params) 
    Dim sales, sale, parts, saleId, value, product

    Set sales = NewDict()

    For Each sale In params
        parts = Split(sale, "-")
        saleId = parts(0)

        ' let's be careful and do a sanity check 
        If Count(parts) = 2 and IsNumeric(saleId) Then
            product = Split(parts(1), ":")

            If Count(product) = 2 Then
                If Not sales.Exists(saleId) Then
                    sales.Add saleId, NewDict()
                End If

                sales(saleId).Add product(0), product(1)
            Else
                ' Invalid parameter format, react accordingly
            End If
        Else
            ' Invalid parameter format, react accordingly
        End If
    Next

    Set ParseSales = sales
End Function
```

Now you can do all kinds of things on the server side

```vb
Dim sales, saleId
Set sales = ParseSales(Request("sales"))

Response.Write sales.Exists("712")        ' -> True
Response.Write sales.Exists("714")        ' -> False
Response.Write sales("712").Count         ' -> 2
Response.Write sales("712")("KR")         ' -> 1
Response.Write sales("712").Exists("XR")  ' -> False

Response.Write Join(sales.Keys(), "; ")         ' -> 712; 713
Response.Write Join(sales("712").Keys(), "; ")  ' -> KR; LR

For Each saleId In sales
    ' saleId will be "712" and so on, use sales(saleId) to get the 
    ' actual object and do something with it
Next
```

Comment: Could you please explain you code to me a bit as well, doesn't seem to work, if I alert the urlVariable right at the end I only get "?sale=". 

Where does the saleId and itemId variable come from in the callback function. Ive read it over and over and can't get my head round it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you call `submitSales` without a parameter, that's why yours does not work. (I suggested not to rely on a global `sales` variable.) You should set a breakpoint in that function and step through the code line by line in your browser's developer tools. It should be easy to understand from that point on. :)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change the call lmao, thanks. Works fine now. 

I will get around to the ASP part soon.

Comment: As I said in a comment to your question - if you are in the process of building the application you could decide to use JScript on the server side instead of VBScript. Data transfer between client and server would certainly be easier via JSON and syntax as well as data structures like objects or arrays are a lot more flexible and powerful than in VBScript. Also there are a lot more powerful JS libraries you can use than VBScript libraries.